# Hide label in certain resolution with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have this wrapper in simple_forms

```
config.wrappers :styled_horizontal_boolean3, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.optional :readonly
  b.use :label, class: 'hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-3 control-label'

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-md-9 checkbox-margin' do |wr|
    wr.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'styled checkbox' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_span_input, class: 'col-md-9', span_class: 'left'
    end

    wr.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    wr.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

This will hide the control-label at lower resolutions, which is great, see screenshot:

[image: Lower resolution]

But I need to find a way to hide the label of the checkbox at larger resolutions, otherwise it's rendered twice, see screenshot:

[image: Higher resolution]

Edit:
This is the HTML generated by simple_form

```
<label class="boolean optional checkbox" for="timesheet_report_uninvoiced">
  <input class="boolean optional col-md-9" id="timesheet_report_uninvoiced" name="timesheet_report[uninvoiced]" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <span class="left">    </span>Uninvoiced only
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it like this:

```
config.wrappers :styled_horizontal_boolean3, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.optional :readonly
  b.use :label, class: 'hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-3 control-label'

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-md-9 checkbox-margin hide-text-medium-large' do |wr|
    wr.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'styled checkbox' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_span_input, class: 'col-md-9', span_class: 'left'
    end

    wr.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    wr.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

And added this to the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
  .hide-text-medium-large
    color: transparent
    -webkit-touch-callout: none
    -webkit-user-select: none
    -khtml-user-select: none
    -moz-user-select: none
    -ms-user-select: none
    user-select: none
```

This will make only the text transparent, the checkbox stays as is, and users can't see or select the hidden text.  As soon as the resolution is lower than 992 it's being displayed.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) of Bootstrap. You might add for example add the `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg` classes to hide it on medium and large screens

Comment: The bootstrap part is clear for me, it's the simple_forms that isn't.  Ideally I should be able to tell simple_forms to get rid of the content of label.  Can't hide the <label> itself since the checkbox is contained within.  I'll make an edit to show the HTML it generates now.

Comment: Ah sorry, don't know much about simple_form unfortunately. You can't get the "Uninvoiced only" to appear inside the `span.left`? If so you could add the `hidden-md` on that element

Comment: Unfortunately not without changing all the views.